# MinGW: 'GetThreadId' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, winapi, gcc, mingw

Почему стандартная функция WinApi GetThreadId() отсутствует в include-файлах пакета MinGW GCC?

Вот минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    DWORD id = GetThreadId(GetCurrentThread());
    printf("id=%X\n",id);
    return 0;
}
```

А вот результат компиляции:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проапгрейдил свой MinGW до версии 9.2.0 - всё равно идентификатор не объявлен; пробовал добавлять processthreadsapi.h, но нет такого файла. К счастью, референс в файле libkernal32.a есть, так что помогло ручное добавление протатипа:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" DWORD WINAPI GetThreadId(HANDLE Thread);

int main()
{
    DWORD id = GetThreadId(GetCurrentThread());
    printf("id=%X\n",id);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако это костыль.
Может у меня какой-то пакет в MinGW не установлен? Или имеется веская причина, почему прототип этой функции не добавили в стандартный хедер? Гугление ничего не дало.

Comment: В MinGW-w64 (в standalone версии и в составе msys2) ваш изначальный код компилируется и работает без ошибок.

Comment: Чему равно значение _WIN32_WINNT при компиляции?

Comment: @Chorkov хмм... _WIN32_WINNT ==0x500. А в документации написано, что должно быть 0x0502 or later. Получается, что у меня старые инклюды, и они по непонятной причине не проапгрейдились...

Comment: @LShadow77 Нет, это означает что установлен режим совместимости со старыми версиями windows. (Где этой функции еще не было.) В принципе, дефайн можно установить руками в нужное значение.

Comment: @Chorkov однако проблема в том, что идентификатор 'GetThreadId' вообще отсутствует в хедерах (я запускал поиск), define не поможет (и я, кстати, пробовал).

Comment: У меня в MSYS2 тоже все работает. Выкиньте обычный MinGW и поставьте себе нормальный MinGW-w64. Свежая версия есть тут: https://www.msys2.org/ или тут: http://winlibs.com/